# Contour Integral with Multiple Poles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-principal-value

I'm reading through a physics textbook and came across the integral in the image below. The author says we're using contour integration for this, but I'm not sure how they are getting 2 terms in the final answer.

Can someone show me how to derive equation (37.17) in the attached image? (Preferably through contour integration.)

Thanks in advance.

[Image of the contour integral to be integrated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vn4G.png)

Comment: The answer contains $+$ because of one [second-order pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles), not because of multiple poles. The $+$ is due to the product rule.

Comment: Does not provide his or her approach to solving the problem.

Comment: @J.G. When you say the "product rule", are you referring to a partial fraction decomposition? What product rule is there other than through taking derivatives of products?

Comment: I'm referring to $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$. My link shows the residue of a second-order pole is proportional to a derivative.

Comment: @J.G. thank you so much for pointing out that derivative, I totally missed that! I got the exact answer from my textbook. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two poles, one in the upper-half plane and the lower-half plane. Assume you close the contour in the upper-half plane. Then you only pick up the contribution from the pole in upper-half plane. Note that the pole is a second-order pole. Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was trying to consider both poles, and now I see why we choose only one :)